# How to adjust Window Rectangle based on determined size of Client Rectangle

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a window that I know the content size determined and I want it to be centered and also size will change when a menu option is picked. I am confused about how should I use the [`GetWindowRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(WINUSER%2FGetWindowRect)%3Bk(GetWindowRect)%3Bk(DevLang-C%2B%2B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue), [`AdjustWindowRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-adjustwindowrect?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(WINUSER%2FAdjustWindowRect)%3Bk(AdjustWindowRect)%3Bk(DevLang-C%2B%2B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue)  and [`MoveWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow) functions together even though I read the documentation, if more experienced members could provide an example with explanation I would be grateful

Thanks to all who take their time to help

Comment: *"I am confused about how should I use the `GetWindowRect()`"* - That's easy: Not at all. The window rectangle is the **result** of calling `AdjustWindowRect[Ex]`.

Comment: Take a look at SetWindowPos and the code example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes

Comment: @IInspectable if you care the elaborate I would be happy

Comment: Once you have decided on the size of your client area, pass that into `AdjustWindowRect[Ex]` (along with the respective window styles and menu flag) and use the updated rectangle to resize your window. If you use (0,0) as the coordinates of the top-left corner of the client rectangle you get a rectangle back that conveniently leaves the top-left corner of the window in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @IInspectable's comment. I created the below method which does both centering and resizing properly for various client sizes of menu options

```
BOOL MainWindow::AdjustWindow()
{
    //use required fields to set rectangle of client area
    RECT clientToWindowRect;
    clientToWindowRect.left = GetScreenCenter().x - GetClientSize().cx / 2;
    clientToWindowRect.top = GetScreenCenter().y - GetClientSize().cy / 2;
    clientToWindowRect.right = GetScreenCenter().x + GetClientSize().cx / 2;
    clientToWindowRect.bottom = GetScreenCenter().y + GetClientSize().cy / 2;
    //send it to  AdjustWindowRect()
    if (!AdjustWindowRect(&clientToWindowRect, 
                           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_MINIMIZEBOX |
                           WS_SYSMENU | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_VISIBLE,
                           TRUE))
    {
        GetLastError();
        return FALSE;
    }
    //use rectangle in MoveWindow()
    if (!MoveWindow(this->Window(),
         CalculateCenter(this->Window(), 
         clientToWindowRect).x,
         CalculateCenter(this->Window(), 
         clientToWindowRect).y, 
         MeasureRect(clientToWindowRect).cx, 
         MeasureRect(clientToWindowRect).cy,
         TRUE))
    {
        GetLastError();
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```